# CPU/Threads during the scraping process

Tags: postgresql

I am a junior developer and have a question about performance in scraping. I noticed that optimizing the script for software, for example, scraping Google and inserting data into PostgreSQL, is not very effective. Regardless of what I use for process management, such as pm2 or systemd, and how many processes I run, the best results come when I set up a similar number of instances of the script as threads on the server processor, correct? I have conducted tests using various configurations, including PostgreSQL with pgBouncer, and the main factor seems to be CPU threads, correct? One approach to optimization is to use a more powerful server or multiple servers, correct?

Comment: welcome, Programming question should be asked on Stack Overflow. Product Suggestions are off-topic. I would suggest that you put your program in the question and as said retry on Stack Overflow